# Generic method with generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, casting, generic-method, generic-interface

I have this method

```
public static void ReadExcelToKeyableList<T, TKey>() where T : IKeyable<TKey>, IExcel
{
    List<T> keyableList = GetList(typeof(T));
    T getKeyable;
```

Part of the code in the method is this:

```
        foreach (IExcel xl in toList)
            if (xl is T)
            {
                (keyableList[keyableList.IndexOf(getKeyable)] = (xl as T)).Update();
            }
```

And i get the next error

> The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because
>   it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint

---

I've tried to change the code to this one:

```
(keyableList[keyableList.IndexOf(getKeyable)] = (xl as IKeyable<TKey>)).Update();
```

And now i get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'DataService.Classes.IKeyable' to
>   'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

---

Why can't i convert IKeyable to T even if i set `where T : IKeyable<TKey>`?

Anyone have any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: Any reason not to just add the `class` constraint?

Comment: The compiler is trying to tell you that since you can't use `as` operator with structs (and a struct can implement `IKeyable<T>`), you want to add a constraint so you can only pass reference types to the generic method with the `class` constraint.

Comment: You can cast `(T)xl` without problems because you're checking if is of type `T`.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria thanks! that's work.